# How to achieve "Last. or First." using proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I am trying to achieve the "last." functionality using Proc SQL instead of data step. Say I have a dataset like below:

```
Account_Id Dept Salary Emp_Status Projects Rating
111         123  7000  Perm       A        5
111         123  7000  Perm       B        4
111         123  7000  Perm       C        5
222         124  6000  Perm       A        5
333         125  7000  Perm       B        4
333         125  7000  Perm       C        5
```

I want only one row in my output for each account_id. So, i want the last.account_id. How can I achieve this using proc sql. I tried using max(monotnic()) while grouping on account_id but did not work. 
Can someone please help. Also, I cannot use or do a sub-query due to some standard project limitations. Is there any other way of doing this in proc sql?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the query you tried.

Comment: On what basis you decide the last entry of each account id? On basis of projects or dept or something else?

Comment: Sure , here it is : `PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE Test AS
SELECT distinct ACCOUNT_ID
       ,Dept
       ,Salary
       ,Emp_status
       ,Projects
       ,Rating
    ,MAX(MONOTONIC()) as ronnum
FROM work.Ratings
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
; QUIT;`

Comment: @ G. Arima, it's just the last account_id, randomly selected, just like the way it's done in data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to do what you want for the sample data you have posted, assuming that you care only about the row order of your input dataset rather than the values of any particular variable to determine the order within by-groups:

```
data have;
input Account_Id Dept Salary Emp_Status $ Projects $ Rating;
cards;
111         123  7000  Perm       A        5
111         123  7000  Perm       B        4
111         123  7000  Perm       C        5
222         124  6000  Perm       A        5
333         125  7000  Perm       B        4
333         125  7000  Perm       C        5
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
    select *, monotonic() as row_id from have
    group by account_id
    having row_id = max(row_id);
quit;
```

This seems quite similar to what you say you've already tried, so if it doesn't work, please provide some sample input data that reproduce the problem.

In general I would advise against using `monotonic()` in production code as it is undocumented and can cause unexpected results in more complex queries. When working with sql you should use a variable to define your row order.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked. I guess using the aggregate function in the having clause does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly state there are no automatic variables in SAS SQL equivalent to first. or last.  The data will need to have columns that support a definitive within group ordering that can be utilized for MAX selection and then applied as join criteria.  `Projects` in your data is a possible candidate:

```
data have;
input Account_Id Dept Salary Emp_Status $ Projects $ Rating;
datalines;
111         123  7000  Perm       A        5
111         123  7000  Perm       B        4
111         123  7000  Perm       C        5
222         124  6000  Perm       A        5
333         125  7000  Perm       B        4
333         125  7000  Perm       C        5
run;

proc sql;
   * standard sql query;
   create table want as
   select have.*
   from have
   join (select account_id, max(projects) as max_projects from have group by account_id) as matched
     on matched.account_id = have.account_id
        and matched.max_projects = have.projects
   ;

   * SAS sql query that does magic auto remerge ;
   create table want as
   select have.*
   from have
   group by account_id
   having projects = max(projects)   
   ;
```

I would avoid `monotonic()`, especially in SQL.  The function is undocumented and not guaranteed to be present or perform equivalently in future releases.  Your data really does need context columns for selecting the within group extrema.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this makes sense, I can try using an aggregate function on a column.