# How to select last element for each ID

Tags: sql, proc-sql

I would like select some elements from the last id

Here an example that I have :

```
id      money
1        200
1        150
1        500
3        50
4        40
4        300
5        110
```

Here what I would like :

```
1        500
3        50
4        300
5        110
```

So like you can see, I took last id and the money who corresponds.

I tried to do a group by id order by id descending with limit 1.  But limit 1 is not available in proc sql from sas and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180757/how-to-achieve-last-or-first-using-proc-sql

Comment: is your list ordered in some way or do you always want the max value?

Comment: What is _last_? Do you have a timestamp column too?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SAS datasets, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  In your case, it looks like you want the maximum value in the second column, in which case you can use aggregation:

```
proc sql;
    select id, max(money)
    from t
    group by id;
```

If you actually mean the last row per `id` based on the ordering in the SAS dataset, I would suggest using a `data` step instead.